How do I get my Stripe createpayment sheet to not hang?
This is my code using the stripe/capacitor community plugin:
import {Stripe} 'from @capacitor-community/stripe'

        try {
            const response = await fetch(`https://fakeurl.com/createpaymentintent`, {
                method: "POST",
                mode: "cors",
                headers: requestHeaders,
                body: JSON.stringify({ amount, currency, firstName, lastName, email })

            })
            const data = await response.json()
            console.log('data success', data.cs, data.customer_id, data.es)

            try {

                console.log('before create payment sheet')
                await Stripe.createPaymentSheet({
                paymentIntentClientSecret: data.cs,
                customerId: data.customer_id,
                customerEphemeralKeySecret: data.es,
                merchantDisplayName: "test app"
            });
            console.log('after payment create')
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error in create payment')
            }

            try {

                const result = await Stripe.presentPaymentSheet()
                console.log('result', result)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error in result')
            }


        } catch (error) {
            console.log('payment failure')
        }

This function hangs after 'before create payment sheet' is logged.  I don't even get an error message from the catch part of the try/catch.
